# Unable to view the page created through a custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, module, ce-1.9.2.1

I am using Magento CE 1.9.2.1. I wrote a custom module for just outputting "Test page Feedback". But, I am unable to access the page (facing 404 error) `http://localhost/magento/index.php/feedback/index` or `http://localhost/magento/feedback/index`. Even, I am unable to find any error in the logs.

Below is my code for the respective files:

/app/etc/modules/MYStore_Feedback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MYStore_Feedback>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MYStore_Feedback>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/MYStore/Feedback/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MYStore_Feedback>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MYStore_Feedback>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <feedback>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>MYStore_Feedback</module>
                    <frontName>feedback</frontName>
                </args>
            </feedback>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

app/code/local/MYStore/Feedback/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php
class MYStore_Feedback_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
    public function indexAction() {
        echo "Test page Feedback";
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you disable the cache or at lease refresh it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be frontName (with uppercase N) and not frontname lowercase in your config.xml file.

Comment: Sorry.. Its not working even after I changed the frontname to frontName.

Comment: I created the module on a fresh Magento on my side and it works perfectly fine. Please try flushing your cache, removing var/cache folders and try again.

Comment: Wow someone is on a downvoting spree. Strange because this answer is correct, you should use frontName, not frontname. You have my upvote.

Comment: Thanks Milan, I'm sure it is the right answer as I personally tested it on my side but anyway ^^

Comment: I disabled the cache and deleted the var/cache folder. But, its same. Its redirecting to 404 error. Should I make any other changes such as folder permissions etc?
I am using WAMP Server.

Comment: I am using WAMP Server (PHP 5.3.13).

Comment: Its the issue with the version. It is working fine in PHP 5.5 version. Thank you.

Comment: Glad you worked it out. Mark the question as answered if we helped you.